# How do I use a local SPM package without a git repository?

Tags: swift-package-manager

Regarding Swift Package Manager, how do I use a local library package as a dependency of an executable package without a git repository? **SwiftPM claims it allows you to pass in a local path in the url field, but then complains that it can't clone the repository.**

from Package.swift

```
    dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    .package(url: "../../../string-calculator/swift/StringCalculator", from: "1.0.0"),
],
```

When running `swift package update` I get the following output:

```
Fetching /Users/tsd037/Documents/Workspace/Misc/tdd-kata/string-calculator/swift/StringCalculator
error: failed to clone; fatal: repository '/Users/tsd037/Documents/Workspace/Misc/tdd-kata/string-calculator/swift/StringCalculator' does not exist
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that even for a local directory you have to create a git repository (local). Just run `git init` in the local directory, `git commit` and add a tag, e.g. `git tag 1.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, found the following solution in the API documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/package/3583304-init
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/package/dependency/3582846-package

Use the "path" parameter instead of "url"

```
 dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    .package(path: "../../../string-calculator/swift/StringCalculator"),
],
```